# Pass the id of button from django template to a view

Tags: python, html, django, excel, view

Below is my views.py file

```
def view_approval(request):   

    utype = request.POST.get('butn')
    print utype
    if utype == 'APP':
        #certain set of funtions
    if utype == 'SRC':
        #certain set of funtions
    else:
        #certain set of funtions
```

And the HTML file:

```
<form  name="feedback22" action="{% url 'view_approval' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
       <input id="bdyBtn" type="button" name="butn" value="APP" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#appModal" >
       <input id="bdyBtn" type="button" name="butn" value="SRC" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#srcModal" >
</form>
```

I have two modals in my HTML page, used for uploading two Excel sheets. So I created a Django view named `view_approval` and placed the code inside it. The code gets executed depending upon the input button clicked. But the issue is, the value of the input button is not reaching the views.
When I printed the value using a print inside the view, it showed a value "None"

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: how in the world that two elements having the same id?

Comment: and also give different value for name attribute..

Comment: you have two same name in both input fields. Check with request.POST.getlist('butn') it will return both field value.

Comment: @NeErAj KuMaR in the name = 'butn', butn is the variable used to pass the values. Also I checked with the getlist, it printed **[ ]**

Comment: @AvinashRaj the 'id' is used for internal css :)

Comment: Then you must provide it in class not in id.